# What are the JSON equivalents to XML XPath and XSLT?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, xslt, xpath

I've used XML and its tools, XPath and XSLT for over a decade.  The query and formatting capability to handle format impedance are extremely useful.

But now, since most of my browser side work is done with JSON, I find it difficult to simply query or format from component to component.

Are there equivalent tools for JSON to handle this?

EDIT: It needs to run in the browser via a JavaScript library to be optimal for our implementation.

Comment: For transforming JSON in the browser, consider Saxon-JS. XSLT 3.0 has capabilities for handling JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There exists the [*JUST.NET library*](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1187172/JUST-JSON-Under-Simple-Transformation).

> JUST stands for JSON Under Simple Transformation.XSLT is a very popular way of transforming XML documents using a simple transformation language.
>
> More and more applications are now using JSON as a data format because it is much simpler and less bulkier than XML.
>
> However, there isn't a very easy way to transforming JSON documents.
>
> I have created a library in .NET which enables the transformation of JSON documents using very a simple transformation language. This is an attempt to create an XSLT parallel for JSON.

So overall the intention of the JUST.NET project is to create an equivalent of XSLT for JSON data. Decide yourself if that fits your needs.

Comment: This sounds great, but... What I didn't state explicitly in my question is that I want to do this browser side, so a .NET implementation won't work.  I need a JavaScript library.

Comment: What a funny little restriction \*g\*. I suggest that you add that information to your question with an edit.

Comment: I did.  Thanks for the suggestion.